# How to populate lead source values dynamically in Suit CRM?

Tags: crm, suitecrm

I want to populate the lead source values in suite CRM dynamically based on logged in user. In the background when a user logs in, Suite CRM has to make a call to an external service and fetch the values to populate the lead source drop down. If it isn't possible with Suite CRM, is there any other CRM(free/paid) which supports such features?

[image]

Comment: Can you post that what you have tried to achieve this? Do you know how to code in SuiteCRM? How to use custom code in metadata for a field?

Comment: That thing in the screenshot doesn't need any code. That was sample data provided by SuiteCRM. Anyone who knows PHP can code in SuiteCRM just download the code and edit it the way you want.

Comment: No, PHP developer will need to learn the SuiteCRM architecture to code in that. Better to explore SuiteCRM first and try some possible ways of doing it. If you face issue in any specific implementation the post your complete code so that you can get help in required areas.

Comment: for a quick tip, you will need to modify field options in view.edit.php(better to modify it in upgrade safe manner). In view.edit.php, get current user object, perform your validation using the object and set the field options accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Will do that.